# Get JSON from link clicked in Webview

Tags: php, android, json, parsing, webview

How can I retrieve the JSON from a link in webview?

Currently I do a Httpget request to a API and get my first JSON and parse it then I display it in my webview I have no issues with that part.  So now I have some links that lead to a API call in my webview i created with the new info from the json I just parsed... EX:

```
String summary = "<html><body> <a href="http://www.mydomain.com/json.php">Get New JSON</a> </body></html>";
webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
```

So when a user clinks that link in the webview i want to get the JSON and be able to parse it. I think I have to use "shouldInterceptRequest"? Can't figure how to implement that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [create and set a WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setWebViewClient%28android.webkit.WebViewClient%29) and override its [shouldOverrideUrlLoading()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) method. That way you get the chance to intercept any links clicked (or redirections, &c).

For example:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        if (url.endsWith(".json"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "json found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```